# how to associate separate session with two different pop-up windows?

Tags: java, session, web-applications, sessionid

I have a java based web application. This is the behaviour I am seeing in my web application:

I am on customer.jsp. I have provided two links on this jsp. On click of these two links two separate pop up opens up. What I notice now is that, same session of parent screen is getting associated with both pop up window. (I got know to about this when I inspected the session id
in debugger mode and when I do any further activity on these pop ups).

For my requirement, I want to associate different session ids to both pop up windows. How should I go about this?

As per my understanding different session ids should should be attached with these browsers as session is specific to browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session id is generated at the server side and associated with the client(browser). And it is possible to keep only one session for one browser instance, even in different tabs. You can get different sessions with different browsers accessing the same url, but for one browser there will be only one session associated no matter how many tabs you open for the same url.   What you will need is to handle the different popups with different identifiers in the same session.